# Create back of hbase data on S3 and the restore

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hbase

I had hbase cluster running on `amazon ec2 nodes`. I want to create the backup of my hbase table. So, I came up with this [tool](http://blog.bizosys.com/2011/12/hbase-backup-to-amazon-s3.html#comment-form). I was able to create the back up of table dummy on s3 using the following command :

```
java com.bizosys.oneline.maintenance.HBaseBackup mode=backup.full backup.folder=s3://mybucket/ tables=dummy
```

But when i tried to restore the same data on some table(model). It failed with the following :

```
`13/10/24 10:52:52 WARN mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Output path is null in cleanup
13/10/24 10:52:52 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0002
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.retrieveBlock(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy5.retrieveBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3InputStream.blockSeekTo(S3InputStream.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3InputStream.read(S3InputStream.java:119)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
13/10/24 10:52:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0002
13/10/24 10:52:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0

Error in Job completetion Params
 tablename   inputputdir
 model  s3://mybucket/Wed_Oct_23_19_45_49_IST_2013/model
Access Failure to s3://mybucket/Wed_Oct_23_19_45_49_IST_2013/model , tries=1
```

`.

```
java com.bizosys.oneline.maintenance.HBaseBackup mode=restore  backup.folder=s3://mybucket/Wed_Oct_23_19_45_49_IST_2013 tables="model"
```

FYI, please don't suggest me that there is an option of installation of hbase as well as back up on EMR. That i know but for some reason i am not using it.